# Should i sign a contract agreeing with an economical offer to work for a company before the last interview?

Tags: contract-law

I am doing an interview process with a company and and they want me to sign a contract which says that i agree with their economical offer before i do the final round of interviews, i am thinking that this is very weird, because depending on what they say to me on the last round of interviews i may not want to work with them, or they do not want to work with me, they what should i do?

It is my first time here, if there is anything else i can do to improve my question, then please let me know.

Comment: Law.se cannot answer "what should I do" Questions. We might be able to advise on the effect of signing such an agreement, but would need details to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> Should i sign a contract agreeing with an economical offer to work for a company before the last interview?

No. Your thought that "*i may not want to work with them*" suggests that you would rather not *bear the risk of mistake*. [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at § 154(b) explains the concept of *bearing the risk of mistake*. Quite the contrary, your description indicates that the final round of interviews could give you the information you need in order to make a decision whether to work there.

When the parties enter a contract, it is presumed that they *willfully and knowingly* commit to the terms and conditions. The company might be attempting to shortchange you by making you preemptively commit to terms you would reject if you knew them. Regardless, your agreement to that contract would subject you to the legal ramifications thereof just as if you fully know the terms.